# Complanarity of three given vectors

Tags: vector-spaces

We have the vectors  $a =3u-2v$ , $b=-2u+v$ and $ c=7u-4v$. Prove that they are complanar.

Comment: Sure, $a-2b=c$. Was that really so hard?

Comment: The vectors u and v are NOT parallel.

Comment: Yes, I am AWARE of that. You asked to prove that they are complanar [sic.].

Comment: I actually thought about doing it with the cross products,I know its not hard..

Comment: copper.hat is "complaining" because you asked to prove they are "complanar". It's a joke based on your typo. After my comment, there is now zero chance of it being funny.

Comment: On the contrary, thanks for explaining!

Comment: No,I still find it funny :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without calculations, using a little theory.
$a,b,c\in span\{u,v\}$. Consequently, $span\{a,b,c\}\subseteq span\{u,v\}$. Since $a\nparallel b$, (you said that $u\nparallel v$), it follows $span\{a,b,c\}\equiv span\{u,v\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Vectors $u,v$, not being parallel, span a plane. That plane contains $a$, $b$, and $c$. Hence these three vectors (and in fact all five) are coplanar by the definition of coplanar.

Answer (score 0):

It will suffice to show that the vector space spanned by $a,b,c$ is a plane, for then they all live on that plane. Note that $a$ and $b$ are linearly independent, so the dimension of the vector space they span is $2$. But $a-2b = c$, so $c$ already lives on the vector space spanned by $a,b$, and hence the vector space spanned by $a,b,c$ is $2$-dimensional, and so a plane.